# Python module variables

Tags: python

In the root of my application i have a app_db.py file that sets a variable. Then in my app/models/models.py i try to

```
from app_db import *
```

and try to access the variables, but it gives an error that the variable is not defined. My app/models contains a **init**.py file and a models.py file. What am i doing wrong? My app_db.py file is simple

```
if os.environ.get('DATABASE_URL') is None:
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'postgresql://mfrtdskrujqfer:tIkrP25Zsl7W3MQtrw0@ec2-184-78-175-240.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/dev03fouea9lm'
else:
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = os.environ['DATABASE_URL']
```

Comment: the variables you want to import must be defined on `__init__.py`

Comment: so the above code goes in the __init__.py file ?

Comment: No, this has nothing to do with an `__init__.py`. – Can you show us the exact error message?

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to `from package import *` then all the things that you would like available must be listed in the `package/__init__.py` files `__all__` entry.

If you `from package import (name1, name2,...)` then you do not have to do so unless the names are prefixed with underscores, (see PEP8 section on name mangling).

Better still of course is to use `import package` and access as `package.name1`, etc.